# Matplotlib, как построить график с логарифмическими шкалами, и не логарифмическими подписями?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Пытаюсь подружится с matplotlib. Как построить график я понял, но не могу нормально заставить рисовать логарифмическую шкалу с не логарифмическими метками. Во первых логарифмические метки, накладываются на нормальные, во вторых, не могу задать начальные координаты, что бы на график по оси у строился от 0.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

x_data = [3, 6, 100, 200, 300, 600] 
y_data = [47, 48, 62, 72, 81, 100]
x_label =  ['3', '6', '100', '200', '300', '600']
y_label = ['47', '48', '62', '72', '81', '100']

_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))

ax.plot(x_data, y_data, color='#539caf', alpha=1)

ax.set_title('График')
ax.set_xlabel('prm')
ax.set_ylabel('углы')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')

# данные для построения
ax.set_xticks(x_data)
ax.set_yticks(y_data)

# подписи осей
ax.set_xticklabels(x_label)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_label)

# лимит построения - не работает, график уплывает
#  он строит по линейной шкале, а в логарифмической не может
# ax.set_xlim(1,1000)
# ax.set_xlim(1,1000)

# Второй вариант
# plt.xscale('log')
# plt.yscale('log')
# plt.yticks(y_data, y_label)
# plt.xticks(x_data, x_label)

ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Ну и когда устанавливаю лимит в 1000 делений по оси х и у, график уплывает.
А так должно выглядеть:

[image: График мечты]

Comment: Прошу прощения за огромное изображение

Comment: вы б хотя б переменные одинаково называли. а то у вас и lable и labla и label...

Comment: ax.set_xlim(0,1000) - почему у вас нижний предел равен нулю? логарифм нуля не определен, поставьте единицу, что-ли...

Comment: Виноват, недоглядел с переменными) Да и ax.set_xlim() всё равно не даёт того что мне нужно, он не строит логарифмической шкале

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict
import math

def logplot(data, title = 'Graph'):
    x_data = []
    y_data = []

    # сортируем словарь в обратном порядке
    sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))

    # Создаём кортеж для данных и кортеж для обозначений
    for x in sorted_dict:
        x_data.append(int(x))

    # Создаём кортеж для данных и кортеж для обозначений
    for x in sorted_dict:
        y_data.append(sorted_dict[x])

    # x_data = [3, 6, 100, 200, 300, 600]
    # y_data = [47, 48, 62, 72, 81, 100]

    x_lable = [1, 3, 6, 10, 100, 200, 300, 600, 1000]
    y_lable = [1, 3, 5, 10, 50, 100, 150, 200, 1000]

    _, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))

    ax.plot(x_data,
            y_data,
            color='#200094',
            alpha=1,
            marker='o',
            markerfacecolor="#ff22aa")
    # задний фон
    rect = ax.patch
    rect.set_facecolor('#bbbabf')
    rect.set_alpha(0.25)

    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel('prm')
    ax.set_ylabel('angles')

    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')

    ax.set_xlim(1, 1000)
    ax.set_ylim(1, 1000)

    # н знаю почему, но как говорится, без этого не работает
    plt.xticks(x_lable)
    plt.yticks(y_lable)
    #
    # # axis signatures
    ax.set_xticklabels(x_lable)
    ax.set_yticklabels(y_lable)



    # добавляем подписи к маркерам
    for i in range(len(y_data)):
        x = x_data[i]
        # тупо что бы было красиво
        if y_data[i] in ('0', '1'):
            add = 1
        elif y_data[i] < 10:
            add = math.ceil(math.log(y_data[i], 10)) * 2
        elif y_data[i] >= 10:
            add = math.ceil(math.log(y_data[i], 10)) * 5
        y = y_data[i] + add

        # отвечает за рисунок
        ax.text(x, y, str(y_data[i]), color='r')

    # Вспомогатtльные линии
    # ax.grid(True, which='major', color='#616161', linestyle='-', alpha=0.5)
    ax.grid(True, which='major', color='black', linestyle='-', alpha=0.5)
    ax.grid(True, which='minor', color='#616161', linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.5)

    plt.show()
```

Реализация так себе, но другого не придумал и удовлетворяет мои задачи
Как результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На самом деле все прекрасно работает и без  xticks и set_xticklabels. Просто замените эти ваши четыре оператора на два: ax.set_xlim(1,1000) и
ax.set_ylim(1,1000). Другое дело, что ваш как бы ответ не отвечает на ваш-же как бы вопрос: как "рисовать логарифмическую шкалу с не логарифмическими метками", т.е. с метками  x_label и y_label. Так что этот ответ считать ответом по сути нельзя.

Comment: Если использовать ax.set_ylim(1,1000)/ax.set_хlim(1,1000) то метки на шкале по осям х и у отображаются в логарифмических шкалах.
Мне же требовалось что бы они отображались не в логарифмических.

Comment: [То что получил](https://imgur.com/dC9FLwv) - так выглядит график если сделать как вы предлагаете
[То что я хотел получить](https://imgur.com/hJICirb)
Возможно я не так описал свою проблему, но в конце концов я получил то что мне нужно было.
Другое дело что на координатной шкале не при наведении курсором не отображаются координаты х и у. Если использовать ax.set_ylim(1,1000)/ax.set_хlim(1,1000) то они отображаются

Comment: Ну, если в вашем представлении 10, 100, 1000 - это "нелогарифмическая шкала", а те же самые числу, указанные через степени 10 - "логарифмическая шкала" -  то это весьма "своебразная" трактовка понятий.  Просто для общего развития: "Логарифмический шкала — шкала, длина отрезка которой пропорциональна логарифму отношения величин". И только. (Т.е. и то что вы получили, и то, что хотели получить - это логарифмические шкалы). А как вы на этой шкале метки отображаете - совсем другая история. Старайтесь все-таки использовать стандартные термины в стандартной, всем понятной трактовке.

Comment: Буду знать, спасибо)